# What is the difference between uniform and gaussian random timer?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

In Apache JMeter, what is the difference between uniform random timer and Gaussian Random Timer?

Comment: These articles might be useful for you to analyse [Gaussian Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Gaussian_Random_Timer) & [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer)

Comment: Hii am still not able to understand there usage . Can you explain.

Comment: can anyone explain deviation in Gaussian Random Timer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Uniform Random Timer** pauses the thread by a factor of:

- The next pseudorandom uniformly-distributed value in range between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive)
- Multiplied by “Random Delay Maximum”
- Plus “Constant Delay Offset”

So the formula is: `|0.X * Random Delay Maximum + Constant Delay Offset|` where X an be the value from 0 to 9 inclusively.

**Gaussian Random Timer** basically uses the same formula, but X is calculated using [Marsaglia polar method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) instead of uniform pseudo-random.

See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) for more detailed explanation of how do above and other JMeter Timers work